# Can i reset my iphone using my laptop?

Tags: ios

I dropped my iPhone 5c and the right hand side of the screen doesn't work but I need to wipe all my data from it, how can I do this using my laptop?

Comment: If you have iCloud setup you likely can log into www.icloud.com and remote wipe your phone as well.

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's [article on restoring iDevices using iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT201252):

> 1. Connect your device to your computer using the cable that came with it.
> 2. Select your iPhone, iPad, or iPod when it appears in iTunes.
> 3. In the Summary panel, click Restore.
> 4. Click Restore again to confirm that you want to restore your device to factory settings and delete all data and content. iTunes will
>      download the device software file and restore your device.
> 5. After your device is restored to factory settings, it will restart. When it does, you’ll see the "Slide to set up” welcome screen. Follow
>      the steps in the device Setup Assistant. You can set up your device as
>      new or use a previous backup. If you restored an iOS device that has
>      cellular service, it will activate after you finish setting up your
>      device.